# how to exctact response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter-plugins

How to extract this kind of response value, I have to use into next request. Can someone help me on extracting the value?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFqgb.png)

I tried using json extractorto get an ID the I need to use for the next request, but the value I'm getting is null

Comment: Hi, how can I decrypt the response data? I need a value for my next request, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the response
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. You will be able to refer extracted value as `${msg}` later on where required.

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JSONPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)